# Adding two comma separated datatable cells to dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, datatable

I have a datatable where I'm currently storing values from it like this:

```
string actualprodrow = "PRODUCT";
string actualprod = (from DataRow dr in wafercond.Rows where (string)dr["Parameter"] == actualprodrow select Convert.ToString(dr["Value"])).FirstOrDefault();
```

Since the order of terms in the table can change I'm searching for the given term and then storing the value for said term.  Recently there became a need to store two different comma separated lists in this table that I need to store and associate together.  The two rows in the table that are pertinent look like this:

[image]

I need to store the values in the way so that operation 12348 is associated with a 10 offset and 84321 is associated with -20 offset.  I know I should store these in a dictionary with operation being the key and offset being the value but I haven't found a way to do this yet.  I know it should follow something along these lines that a coworker sent from one of his projects:

```
Dictionary<string, string> offsets = t.Select(item => item.Split(',')).ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]);
```

Any help as to how to get this done would be great appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to provide some more details.  Confused by what "PRODUCT" is representing in your example.

Comment: This is just an example of how I'm storing one item from the datatable.  I'm looking through the parameter column to find a term (in this case "PRODUCT") then storing the value for that term (like "ABCD".  This worked fine previously but the additional need of the comma separated list has complicated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I have a good handle on what you're doing, so this is a rough suggestion.
I would maybe get your Operations first and put those into a dictionary, then get your offsets and split them into a list.  Loop thru and using an index set the value of the dictionary based on the offset.

```
string actualprodrow = "Operation";
string actualprod = (from DataRow dr in wafercond.Rows 
                        where (string)dr["Parameter"] == actualprodrow 
                        select Convert.ToString(dr["Value"])).FirstOrDefault();

var operationDictionary = actualprod.Split(new string[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToDictionary(key => key, v => string.Empty);

actualprodrow = "Offset";
actualprod = (from DataRow dr in wafercond.Rows
                     where (string)dr["Parameter"] == actualprodrow
                     select Convert.ToString(dr["Value"])).FirstOrDefault();

var offsetSplit =  actualprod.Split(new string[]{","}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < operationDictionary.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    var key = operationDictionary.Keys.ElementAt(i);
    operationDictionary[key] = offsetSplit[i];
}
```

Comment: @ejyoung give me an upvote if this helped solve the problem